# how can i get a object from json in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, jsx

i have to get some data from a complex objects json (in my case is: valor_custo_fornecedor from the detalhe object, how can i do this ?
[image: Here is the image of my json api]

i already tried with axios like this:

```
const [valorCusto, setValorCusto] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('MY API LINK').then((res) => {
    let valor = res.detalhe.valor_custo_fornecedor;

    setValorCusto(res.valorCusto.valor_custo_fornecedor);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your response is an array of objects. Either loop over the arrays or select the desired index from the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell without seeing the complete json what key/value pairs exist in the data, but from what I can see you are passing a value that does not seem to exist in the data to `setValorCusto`, namely: `res.valorCusto.valor_custo_fornecedor`

I am guessing what you want to pass to `setValorCusto` is the `valor` variable that you have defined above? However the `res.data.detalhe`is as others have replied an array, which you would either have to iterate through or specify an index for.

Another detail, not relating to the question in itself, is that I would add a dependency array to the effect, so that this api request is not called on every component re-render. So the end result would look something like this:

```
const [valorCusto, setValorCusto] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('MY API LINK').then((res) => {
    const valor = res.data.detalhe.map((detalheItem) => {
        return detalheItem.valor_custo_fornecedor;
    });

    setValorCusto(valor);
  });
}, []);
```

Notice the empty array as the second parameter in the `useEffect` call. This means that the effect will only be run on the initial rendering of the component.

Then you can access the value by simply using `valorCusto` wherever you need it in the component.

Comment: the console say : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'valor_custo_fornecedor')

Comment: I just edited, cause I realized that I missed that the `res.detalhe` is an array of objects, so you need to iterate through that array (like in my edited answer), to get all the values, or specify an index like `res.detalhe[0].valor_custo_fornecedor`. Let me know if that works!

Comment: Given that you set the default state of `valorCusto` to be an empty array, I assumed you wanted to get an array with the values.

Comment: i think you right but im console show like this: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: i think we are to close haha, but,  now the error is :Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Ah okay! I realized that you also need to access `res.data` with axios to get the actual json data returned by the request. I updated my answer with this!

Comment: And also that you don't need to parse it because I think Axios does that by default I think.

Comment: hi return to map error

Comment: What do you get if you log the response with `console.log(res.data)`? Cause it seems to not find detalhe at all.

Comment: i do console.log(valorCusto)

Comment: Oh, wait. So the map error is not happening within the `axios.get` request? Cause I was referring to that it seems like `res.data.detalhe`is undefined, and I wanted to see what `res.data` looks like to figure out if we are getting the proper response at all, by logging it after the request is made!

Comment: so if you add a `console.log(res.data)` above the `valor`definition, what does it log when you run it?

Comment: this: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: Is it not logging anything above that? Comment out the everything else within the `.then` callback for now, cause it might prevent the application from running the `console.log(res.data)`

Comment: so:
`axios.get('MY API LINK').then((res) => console.log(res.data));`

Comment: This is just temporary, to see that we actually get the proper data.

Comment: Oh and, just to make sure, you have replaced the `'MY API LINK'` with the actual api endpoint right?

Comment: I had already changed the api , it was just a comma so there was an error in the map now it's working correctly ty for the help

Comment: Ah! Great, glad to hear it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

After setting response in setValorCusto ; you can loop over you state variable and get the desired value

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers state. What you are returning from your API is an array of objects. Currently in your code, that array lives inside the response object. So in this snippet below:

```
axios.get('MY API LINK').then((res) => {
    let valor = res.detalhe.valor_custo_fornecedor;
```

You need to specify from which item in the array you would like to get the *detalhe* object from (like res[0].detalhe).

One way you could do if you like to use everything from the array, is to store the entire array in your useState. Afterwards, you could loop over the array and do something with the objects inside of it.

PS. If you're not entirely sure what the state holds. You could log it to the page by doing something like `<div>{JSON.stringify(valorCusto)}</div>`

```
export default function App() {
  const [valorCusto, setValorCusto] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("API");
      const data = await res.data;
      setValorCusto(data);
    };
    getData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <main>
      <div>
        {valorCusto.map((item) => {
          <div>{item.id}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert json like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('MY API LINK').then((res) => {
    let obj = JSON.parse(res.detalhe.valor_custo_fornecedor)
  });
});
```